# How to load and save checkbox values in a listview

Tags: android, listview, checkbox, sharedpreferences

I have a listview full of text, but each row has also got a checkbox. When `onCreate()` is called I want it to load the checkbox values from `sharedpreferences` and apply them to the checkboxes. Also when the `onPaused()` is called, I want it to save checkbox values.

Anyone got idea how to do that???

P.S. I have been reading stuff for a little and I have found the custom `adapters` but I don't quite get the point of them. If anyone can explain me that, it would be also appreciated.

Comment: Did u try with onscrolllistener.

Comment: Nope, but it sounds like that, that is not the thing i'm looking for...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When extending an custom `Adapter`, you're precisely implementing stuff like you described. In your case, seems that an `ArrayAdapter` is good enough to achieve it.

This adapter has a `getView()` method which will be called for each of your rows, and which basically processes those rows and *you* implement how they should be shown. This method has 3 parameters, the first one is the `position` of the row being rendered. The second one is a `View` that, vaguely talking, represents the layout of the entire row. THe third one represents the parent of the `View`. This way, assuming your second parameter is called `convertView`, you can do something like:

```
CheckBox cb = convertView.findViewById(R.id.myCheckbox);
```

And set call `cb.isChecked(...)` with the appropriate value to show the current's row value for that checkbox.

Some useful links:

- [ArrayAdapter's reference](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html)
- [An example of ArrayAdapter](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html#arrayAdapter)

Comment: Okay, thats about saving but how about loading?

Comment: Oh and by the way, when is the getView() method called?

Comment: Nope, that's about loading. Each time a row is rendered, this method is called so there's when you get the value from within your `SharedPreferences` and set it accordingly. The way you save it depends on your implementation, but if you're saving it in `SharedPreference`s it's pretty easy to both load/store. If you're saving the values in a database, it's a bit more complex but also perfectly doable. Or even getting them from a remote webservice. It pretty much depends on you implementation.

Comment: It's automatically called when your `ListView` is loaded. That means that when your `ListView` is shown, it will show up X rows (depending on your layout's implementation), `getView()` therefore will be called for each of these rows, modifying the corresponding three parameters I've described above to fit each of them.

Comment: Okay. One (probably) last question. Where to add my implementation? Should I subclass arrayadapter?

Comment: Yes, that's it. You create a separate class that `extends ArrayAdapter<Whatever>`, and just override the `getView(...)` method. You'll find a nice example in the second link I've posted in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with an android pre implemented list view with a checkbox. If there is one, then there should be a way to check them according to position. But I suggest you use a custom ArrayAdapter and define your checkbox. And in getView(), you just check the position and set your checkboxes checked according to the positions.

Edit: Actually, here's an edit for an example of the whole process.

MyAdapter class:

```
package com.example.stackover;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;

public class MyAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    ArrayList<Integer> checkBoxList;
    ListActivity mListActivity;

    public MyAdapter(ListActivity mListActivity, ArrayList<Integer> checkBoxList) {
        this.mListActivity = mListActivity;
        this.checkBoxList = checkBoxList;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return checkBoxList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return checkBoxList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View row=convertView;
        RowWrapper wrapper = null;
        if (row==null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = mListActivity.getLayoutInflater();
            row=inflater.inflate(R.layout.listrow, parent, false);
            wrapper=new RowWrapper(row);
            row.setTag(wrapper);
        }
        if(checkBoxList.contains(position)) {
            wrapper.getCb().setSelected(true);
        }
        return(row);
    }

}
```

RowWrapper class:

```
package com.example.stackover;

import android.view.View;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class RowWrapper {
    View        base;
    TextView    description = null;
    CheckBox    cb    = null;

    public RowWrapper(View base) {
        this.base=base;
    }

    public TextView getDescription() {
        if (description==null) {
            description=(TextView)base.findViewById(R.id.description);
        }
        return(description);
    }
    public TextView getCb() {
        if (cb==null) {
            cb=(CheckBox)base.findViewById(R.id.cb);
        }
        return(cb);
    }

    public View getBase(){
        return this.base;
    }
}
```

And your listrow.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/description"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <CheckBox 
        android:id="@+id/cb"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>


</LinearLayout>
```

And in your ListActivity, or ListFragment, you create your MyAdapter and set the adapter with the constructor taking your activity and your checkbox list from your shared pref. If you want to change the description textview, you do it the same way with another array that holds your text and set them in getView() according to your position.

Comment: On second thought, make your array object boolean. I dunno why I thought you would need a type Integer. In the end your array should only indicate if your row is checked or not :)